# ZEND: Appending XML Data to SQLDataBase(XML)

Tags: php, mysql, xml, zend-framework

My Issue: Unable to append XML data to prexisting XML data in a MYSQL database.

I have an array - $buyer. Inside this array is a $key and $value similar to (shippingTotal => 55). What I want to do is use something similar to

```
$param = array(
 'shippingTotal' => $shippingTotal
);
 $where['quote_data = ?'] = $quoteNumber
$n = $db->update('quote_xml', simplexml_load_string($param), $where);
```

My hiccup is that the current data inside quote_data is an XML element containing LOTS of information. Is there any way to just "stick" shippingTotal into said existing XML? When I use the above code I just end up with quote_data becoming empty.

I also created a variable called $shippingTotal so that I wouldn't have to use $buyer['shippingTotal']. Still not functional.

Thank you for your time and assistance with this issue.
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues with this:

First, `simplexml_load_string` doesn't accept array parameters, only XML strings.  Since the `$params` is not a valid argument, it is returning boolean `false`.  Even when successful, it returns a `SimpleXMLElement`.  To convert that to an XML string, you would have to call the `asXML()` method on the returned object before passing it to `Zend_Db_Table::update()`.

Second, most likely XML cannot just be "appended" to other XML.  I don't know exactly what your table holds, but the XML needs to be programmatically added to the existing XML.  You can't append XML because the data you want to add needs to be added to the proper nodes.

What you will have to do is first read the value of that column, parse it using `SimpleXML`, add your new data to the appropriate node in the document using one of the [SimpleXML functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and then perform the update.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Would it be easier to "download" or capture the entire XML string into a variable, and then just "erase and replace" everything in that specific part of the table? Maybe explode the XML data into an array, append the array to the matching array, and then return it all to XML form? It just seems sort of roundabout and complicated...

Comment: If you need to manipulate the existing XML, select the XML string from your table, load it (`$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string_from_database);`), add or update the data you want either by changing an existing node, or adding a new child node in the appropriate location, convert it back to a string (`$xmlStr = $xml->asXML();`), and then call `Zend_Db_Table::update()` with `$xmlStr` as the data.

Comment: No problem, post back if you have further questions or issues.